# problem with import qt in python

Tags: python

I want to use qt with python. 
"import qt" return me :"ImportError: No module named qt". I already instaled pyqt.

what I hve to install in order to activate "import qt"

Thank You

Comment: This is really a google question. I would say read this: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~afedosov/qttut/

Comment: Also, I would consider PySide.

Comment: Eli's answer is correct if you have installed PyQt4.  You are probably looking at an example that uses PyQt3, which had a `qt` module you could import.

Comment: @Michael: insightful catch ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The current PyQt comes in the `PyQt4` package, which has several modules. You almost always need to start with:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

Add other imports as necessary if you need additional sub-modules of PyQt (like `QtNetwork`, `QtSql` etc).

---

Tip for the future: find the `lib/site-packages` library of your Python installation and look at the packages in there if you're not sure about the name after installing.

Also, arm yourself with a PyQt tutorial - any decent one covers this in the first few paragraphs.

Comment: Also, `from PyQt4 import Qt`. Contains the most commonly-used classes and is shorter to type.

Comment: @delnan: I must confess that personally I `import *` when using `PyQt` because all classes start with `Q` anyway, and it really saves a lot of typing for large amounts of code

Answer (score 3):

`import PyQt4` works for me fine.

Comment: `import PyQt4` doesn't suffice to make sure that `PyQt` has been successfully linked to a working `Qt` installation. Either can be broken (linking or the `Qt` installation). Doing `from PyQt4 import QtGui` does expose such issues, e.g., `dlopen` failures.