# Can't import Qt and PySide in Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, import, pyside, python-3.4, qt4.8

I have installed:

PySide with `sudo apt-get install python3-pyside`,

Qt-5.3, which is in `/home/Qt/` (didn't knew yet PySide doesn't support that version) and

Qt-4.8.6 in `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/`

What I get when trying to import PySide or Qt:

```
ImportError: No module named Qt

ImportError: No module named PySide
```

I'm running Python 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and don't know freaking solution.

`from PySide import QtCore` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'
```

What should I do to make `import` work?

Comment: check here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729121/installed-pyside-but-cant-import-it-no-module-named-pyside) and here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766539/problem-with-import-qt-in-python)

Comment: pip install PySide

'Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_imagine/PySide/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KANf5Z-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_username/PySide
Storing debug log for failure in /home/username/.pip/pip.l'


pip install Qt

'No distributions at all found for Qt'

Comment: @Fred. You don't need to install Qt5 (which is not supported by PySide) and you don't need to install Qt4 separately, either. Your system must already have Qt4 installed if you were able to install `python3-pyside` (because it's a dependency). Run `python3` in a console to start an interactive session, and then enter `from PySide import QtCore`. If you get an error, edit your question and post the **whole** traceback.

Comment: updated, also adding line to ~/.bashrc pointing to PySide installation folder didn't seem to work

Comment: @Fred. Okay enter `import sysconfig` and then `sysconfig.get_path('platlib')`. That should show you the `site-packages` directory where the PySide files were installed (on ubuntu, it will probably be `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`). Have a look in that directory to see what's there (you should see a `PySide` directory containing some `*.so` files).

Comment: I get `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` (no PySide is there, nor in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`)
I have got PySide dir with `*.so` files in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.
I'm guessing I should change path? How?

Comment: @Fred. You're running the wrong python. The ubuntu packages you installed were for **python3**, and will have been installed under `/usr/lib`, not `/usr/local/lib`. You need to run `/usr/bin/python3`, and then try importing PySide.

Comment: import works for `/usr/bin/python3` which is python `3.4.0` but I want to run it under `3.4.2`

Comment: @Fred. Well, hopefully you've got the message now, that packages are always installed for *a specific python*. So you have to ensure you run the right python executable whenever you attempt to install new packages.